# How to overwrite someone elses master with branch DD as a collaborator?

Tags: git, github, repository

Dave has a repo where I am collaborator.

I have forked the repo, made huge changes in branch `DD`.
In the meantime Dave has merged some off my other PRs into master.

I made a PR for `DD`, it couldn't get merged automatically.
Dave told me to merge `master` into `DD`. So I did `git fetch`, merged `master` into `DD` and solved all the conflicts. Still it cant me merged automatically.

So now I just want to overwrite the damn thing. (Asked Dave first ofc)

I tried to run: `git push -f upstream master` from inside branch `DD`.
Next line says Everything is update. I cant see any changes in my fork, or Dave's repo.

So the question is: how can I overwrite Dave master repo?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have made your changes in branch `DD` (and not made a single commit to `master`), it make sense that git replies 'everything is up-to-date'.

Pushing your `DD` branch on `upstream/master` would be a bad idea, as it would erase `master` history, and break previous merges to `master` (which, again, would be completely different)

It would be best if you could:

- reset `DD` to before your merge with `master`
- fetch `upstream`
- rebase `DD` on top of `upstream/master`

  ```
  git checkout DD
  git rebase master
  ```

Then you could make your PR from `yourFork/DD` branch.